# saving time after php sessions ends

Tags: php, session, cookies, destroy

I've written a script (php) that make use of sessions so that it ends after the browser is restarted, and also scripted a "log out" functionality (with destroy session and also deleting cookie from the browser).

And here is my issue:

When the user willingly logs out the time is saved by my script. But I can not control the cases in which the browser is restarted or closed.

Is there any method I can use to handle those cases too ? Thanks ...

Comment: Want to know when the user closes the browser? Maybe could do an ajax call?

Comment: as far as I remember, you have to detect document close event(can't remember the name), and then send AJAX request to save data.

Comment: @Maciekp: what if client just lost his internet connection? What event to handle? ;-)

Comment: In this situation , when browser closes session ends, and I want to save this session ending time. I need it because I am making in profile when user was last seen on site

Comment: @DaHaKa: "and I want to save this session ending time" -- what for?

Comment: Document closing events are far too inconsistent and you can't really rely on them, the best you can do is check for "activity | inactivity", perhaps you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish, can you share some more detail?

Comment: @DaHaKa for the "User last seen on (insert time here)" part i would recommend saving the time on the last activity the user had with your system or fired an event you are watching for eg: "logged in", "searched for content", "viewed article", perhaps something like "updated profile", checking for events is going to be far more reliable and consistent because thats really what you need, to know when the user last had interaction with your site

Comment: Or just send ajax request every 10-20seconds to update status, but that could harm your db, if there are many users :)

Answer (score 4):

If there is no request from the browser, your server-side (PHP) won't notice.

However, if you update a last activity timestamp in your database, you would know when the last activity was. As sessions get destroyed after some time, the last activity for that user will remain in the database until next login.

Comment: I'd think this is the solution, moreover if you're concerned about the user's last visit you should probably either just update the timestamp for logged-in users or write your own session handler which tracks last session access time. Of course session data gets purged from time to time (see garbage collection), so if you're that interested in timestamps, the first option is the way to go. That way you'll always have users' last visit times.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the user page to check in with ajax at some reasonable interval to the server. (5 min?) And then run a job on the server every 5 min to check for users who hadn't checked in in that long. You could assume their time of closing the window or losing their connection was between their last check in and the current time and then destroy the session.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind an AJAX event to the unload Javascript event.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'someLogoutRequest.php'
   });
});
```

Comment: Multiple tabs open of the same site - would that cause a problem?

Comment: ... and as I mentioned in the comments - what if client just lost his connection?

Comment: The unload event is specific to the tab, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @zerkms I am not sure what he is trying to do, he just asked how to detect if the user restarted his browser or closed it. :/

Comment: @jjs9534: sure it is, and **it is** an issue. User just closed one site tab of 100 opened and you sent a message that user has finished his working with site. That's just wrong: closing browser != closing tab

Comment: to say true, I have not thought about that, I was thinking that it is probably possible to detect when all tabs are closed from the current site

Comment: @DaHaKa: tabs don't know about each other

Comment: I didn't read the entire conversation. But i used `LocalStorage` to solve some Browser tab related issues. Ex. in one of my project i have a situation that i need to know whether user opened multiple tabs or not and also i need to know in which module currently user standing without any ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Sessions typically die upon a browser closing (assuming your not confusing cookies and sessions.) But, you could add an extra session that stores a time stamp that anything after that timestamp time wise. Is void, and clears the session. You would generally renew this timestamp as the user navigates so it doesnt timeout mid navigation. Though Im still not one hundred percent clear what your trying to do and why. So my answer could be a mute concept for the need. jjs9543 has a not so bad suggestion, though that suggestion would fail if Javascript is disabled on a users browser (which I can't picture being as common as a few year back but none the less worth saying).